# Understanding Theorem 5.5. of Titchmarsh's Book

Tags: summation, proof-explanation, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, estimation

I have two questions regarding the proof of [Theorem 5.5.](https://imgur.com/a/YA6iL9f) of Titchmarsh's book *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function*:

**Green-underlined:** How from the $O$-term $$\mathcal{O} {\Bigg(\mu + \sum_{r=1}^{\mu -1} \min (\mu, |\csc \dfrac{tr}{2(a+ \nu \mu)^2}|\Bigg)}^{\frac12},$$ the green-underlined equality is achieved? I worked on this for a while and even my guess wouldn't help to achieve a rigorous proof: First by $(a+b)^{\frac12} \le a^{\frac12} + b^{\frac12}$  it brings the sqrt root inside (?) then instead of having $\sum_{\nu}^{N+1}$ behind the sqrt root it is inside it by comes twice (like $a = (a^2)^{\frac12}$ but is this reasonable?!

**Orange-underlined:** I couldn't understand the whole paragraph starting from "Now" which is underlined by an orange line. For more clearance, I explain my thoughts: **A)** I am not a native speaker; what does it mean "the least value but two of"? And why one of the sine terms is greater than $Ar / {\mu}^2$? **B)** The difference of two consecutive terms (i.e. the equality comes just after "Now") is roughly $t r \mu / a^3$ and it is roughly equals to $r / {\mu}^2$ so $tr / 2(a+ \nu \mu)^2$ are distributed on a line partitioned with intervals of length $r / {\mu}^2$, and what it has to do with $\sin$ of theses values?

***Update:** I have the answer for the first question: It's Holder's Inequality. Still the second question remains! My second question is asking for a simple clear explanation of what's going on the mentioned paragraph.*

Comment: If the values are $v_0<v_1<v_2<v_3<\dots$ then $v_0$ is the least value, $v_1$ is the least value but one, $v_2$ is the least value but two. It's very old-fashioned I reckon.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, thanks! Not in a million years I could guess that meaning :) - {Still I couldn't solve the second question}